# Не работают импорты react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Решил сделать приложение на VK-UI. И столкнулся с проблемой - импорты отказываются работать.

Извиняюсь ошибку забыл.Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Код взят из документации к vk-ui.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { View, Panel, PanelHeader, Header, Group, Cell } from '@vkontakte/vkui';
import '@vkontakte/vkui/dist/vkui.css';

function App () {
  return (
    <View activePanel="main">
      <Panel id="main">
        <PanelHeader>VKUI</PanelHeader>
        <Group header={<Header mode="secondary">Items</Header>}>
          <Cell>Hello</Cell>
          <Cell>World</Cell>
        </Group>
      </Panel>
    </View>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover"/>
    <link href="src/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А вы запускайте как, просто открывайте как файл html или с помощью локального/веб сервера ?

Comment: с помощью сервера ubuntu apache

Comment: npx create-react-app пробывали?

Comment: [Node](https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/), [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/), [React](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Набираешь `npx create-react-app`. Далее очищаешь папку src. Потом создаешь файл index.js и вставляешь в него этот код. В терминале набираешь `npm strat`